# How can I remove the Windows 10 Home pin sign-in with a batch script?

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch, batch-file

I have

```
powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_NONE CONSOLELOCK 0
powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_NONE CONSOLELOCK 0
```

in my batch script but if I restart the machine or put the machine to sleep and come back, Windows will still prompt me for a pin. Is there any to disable the pin with only a batch script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kinds of settings are usually done in the GUI on windows (e.g. `netplwiz`), but Microsoft has a command line utility called `autologon` for this. Download it from [the Microsoft site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon)

After you have the tool you can add to your batch script

```
Autologon  <userName> <domainName> <password>
```